# ASP.NET MVC Website Read File from Disk Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading a text file containing an insert statement for SQL using C# in an MVC Website I'm working on. When debugging the function I'm using works fine and the insert occurs. But once I publish the site and run it on my local machine (with IIS set-up to use asp.net 4.0 even) it doesn't seem to work.

```
        if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files["txtImportFile"] != null)
        {
            //newFilePath = Server.MapPath("\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + Request.Files["txtImportFile"].FileName);
            string[] temp_string = Request.Files["txtImportFile"].FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
            string temp_filename = temp_string[temp_string.Count() - 1];
            //newFilePath = Server.MapPath("\\temp\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + Request.Files["txtImportFile"].FileName);
            newFilePath = Server.MapPath("\\temp\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + temp_filename);
            Request.Files["txtImportFile"].SaveAs(newFilePath);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newFilePath);
            string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            Models.WingsRemoteDbLibrary dbLib = new Models.WingsRemoteDbLibrary();
            string update_message = dbLib.UpdateSlaveItemsTable(contents);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(newFilePath))
                System.IO.File.Delete(newFilePath);

            RandomPopupView(update_message);
        }
```

I hope my explanation doesn't sound vague. I'll try my best to answer any further questions. Thanks.

Comment: If the current answers aren't helping, can I strongly suggest you add more details about the actual error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround:

Instead of using

```
Server.MapPath("\\temp\\"...
```

Create folder under root with name "temp" and use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~\\temp....
```

Comment: I'm testing this on my staging website and it works. Now I just need to know what's the difference between Server.MapPath & HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath

Answer (score 1):

Well, "it doesn't seem to work" is pretty vague - a bit more detail would be nice! But it sounds like a permissions issue. The default profile in IIS has very little access to the disk, *especially* write access. It isn't really a good idea to write inside your own site *anyway* (I'd use an unrelated part of the disk, myself), but you will need to configure IIS to run the application in a specific *named* identity, with access to the disk. Configuring the account *itself* (not IIS - the account; for example granting "logon as a service") to run as an ASP.NET account is not particularly trivial, unfortunately.

Another thought: is your app a sub-application, i.e. is your app-root `/`, or is it `/MyApp/` ? The reason I ask is your use of `MapPath` might be better expressed relative to the app-root, i.e. `~/temp/` - but again I stress; writing inside the app is risky. You *really* want that folder to be non-executing.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation is vague. I did think about access as a factor. My code makes a temporary directory to store the file on the server before being read.

Comment: Allowing an account to "Logon as service" is not trivial, but it is not hard by any means: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/b2aa4009-a392-4817-aecc-5e6c0d982319

Comment: @Erick - and it creates successfully? adding another thought, btw

Comment: @Nate - yes, it is the other 6 things you need, and remembering them, that get painful ;p

Comment: Based on code, it does (it even works when I step-into the code during debug and check the directory if it exist). But after the file is created it is deleted afterwards to avoid unwanted files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an alternative solution to this problem. You can avoid messing with path and file system altogether if you can 'bake' the file into assembly at build time. Here is how you can do this:

1. In Visual Studio solution explorer right click on a file and go to Properties.
2. Set Build Action to 'Embedded Resource'.
3. Later you can read the file using [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx):

   ```
       var stream = GetType()
           .Assembly
           .GetManifestResourceStream("YourNameSpace.Folder.YourFile.txt");

       using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
           var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
   ```

   More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314140/625332).