# Asp.net Web API cant read file from file path

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, azure, path

I am developing an azure asp.net web api 2 ,and in my api i am trying to read a dataset ,however i couldnt get my dataset.csv path.I connect to ftp server and i found the rout is : ..../site/wwwroot/dataset.csv this ,

I tried this

```
string path = "/site/wwwroot/dataset.csv";
```

and also this

```
string path=Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "dataset.csv");
```

however none of them is working i couldnt read the data file , how can i read it ?

Thanks

Comment: How about `Server.MapPath("~/dataset.csv");`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath()` instead:

```
string path=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~\\dataset.csv");
```

> Oh, and a friendly ask: please search StackOverflow before posting questions - this has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699079/asp-net-mvc-website-read-file-from-disk-problem)

Comment: If it's a duplicate, then vote to close as such, don't add an answer.

Comment: Just about to vote to close, but as a courtesy to a new member, I also posted the answer in order to avoid seeming unwelcoming or harsh.

Comment: Then a comment would have sufficed :)